# Hbase put command not working for column names

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have to put below 2 rows in my hbase table :

```
put 'TABLE', 'ABC::ABC::NLOC','data:document','myvalue'

put 'TABLE', 'ABC::ABC::NLOC','data:meta:test','values'
```

But after executing this command , i am unable to see the 2 nd command creating a column data:meta:test.

```
hbase(main):003:0> get 'TABLE', 'ABC::ABC::NLOC'
COLUMN                                              CELL                                                                                                                                                 

 data:document                                      timestamp=1528398479692, value=profile data - POST!                                                                                                                                                                                               
 data:meta                                          timestamp=1528398532570, value=values                                                                                                        
2 row(s) in 0.0220 seconds
```

How can i see the column as `data:meta:test`, should i use hbase put in a dieffernt way? any help please

Comment: what you want to achive using `put 'TABLE', 'ABC::ABC::NLOC','data:meta:test','values'` ?

Comment: the column name  will   intercepted by “：” you  can use  scan  to  show your column name   it is ''data:meta '' not   'data:meta:test'